# Disable Wordpress Visual editor tab only on single page - WP 5.3+

Tags: php, wordpress, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I am trying to disable the Wordpress Visual / Rich text editor only on a single page.

I have found a few solutions floating around, but it seems that they're all outdated as the code doesn't seem to work with WP 5.3+

Currently, I am using the following code for the page with ID 353

```
function tn_disable_visual_editor( $can ) {
global $post;
if ( 353 == $post->ID )
return false;
return $can;
}
add_filter( 'user_can_richedit', ' tn_disable_visual_editor ' );
```

But the issue is that it disables the Visual editor everywhere on all pages and posts.

How can I fix this code?